# Rule sends two emails

Tags: email, civirules

We have a form that lets folks add themselves to our mailing list.  When they do so, we have a rule that adds them to a couple of groups, and sends them a "Welcome" email.

Lately, the rule has begun sending out TWO identical emails, less than a minute apart, to each new contact.  The rule looks like this:

---

Linked Trigger:  Contact of any type is added

Linked Condition(s):

Linked Action(s):

Send E-mail Send email from "OrgName (info@OurOrg.org using primary email address)" with Template "Welcome new sign-ups" to the contact and bcc to me@OurOrg.org

Add Contact to a Group  Add contact to group(s): Full Mailing List, Monthly Newsletter

---

Both emails appear in the "Activities" list for the new contact, and I get bccs of both of them.  No entries in the log.  All our other emails are working fine.

Any ideas why this is happening, or how to fix it?

The site is running CiviCRM 5.35.1. on WordPress 5.7.1
CiviRules: Version 2.23
Civirules logger: Version 1.1
Email API: Version 2.2

Comment: It might be related. I did not investigate enough to be sure https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/issues/99#note_59222

Comment: It might have something to do with the core processes inside CiviCRM when entering a new contact.  I find in the documentation about triggers:  "Sometimes an entity is created and then immediately changed so although it might seem that you want an "is added" trigger, you may need to use an "is changed" trigger instead."  But I cannot see any way to write a trigger for "contact is added" other than "Contact is added".

Comment: Still puzzled by this.  I don't even see any way to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Try adding to your rule for email address is Primary and if that does not work try "is not primary"